# error when using random graph generator in NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to create a graph F with a degree sequence of another 
graph G. 
The code is this

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# some code 
    deg_sequence = nx.degree(G).values()   
    print nx.is_valid_degree_sequence(deg_sequence)
    F = nx.random_degree_sequence_graph(deg_sequence, seed=None, tries=10)
```

but I get this error

> True
>    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute
>   'random_degree_sequence_graph'

I just updated Networkx. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What does `print nx.__version__` tell you? My networkx 1.6 has that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched the documentation for nx.random_degree_sequence_graph, and it is a new function in version1.6 .

try:

```
easy_install networkx==1.6
```

:)

Comment: I already have it, I did easy_install networkx a few hours ago, bust still doesn't work

Comment: maybe have an older version of networkx? check the version first